# Prove that if $f(x+t)\geq f(x)-t^2$ for all $t>0$, then $f$ must be non-decreasing.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+t)\geq f(x)-t^2$ for all $t>0$. Prove that $f$ must be non-decreasing.

My work:

Must prove that $f(x+y)\geq f(x)$ for all $y>0$. So this is equivalent to showing that given $y>0$ $f(x+y)\geq f(x)-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Now, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f(x+nt)\geq f(x)-nt^2$. Let $y>0$ be fixed. Now let $\epsilon>0$. Then let $\displaystyle t=\frac{\epsilon}{y}$. Then I can prove the result only if $\displaystyle \frac{y}{t}$ is a natural number. What can I do to show this if $\displaystyle \frac{y}{t}$ is not a natural number? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are there any assumptions about $f$ which you haven't mentioned? Continuous? Differentiable?

Comment: No. This is all.

Comment: Hint: given $x$ and $t>0$, use the inequality to get $f(x+t)\geq f(x)-t^2$, and then $f(x+t/2+ t/2)\geq f(x)-t^2/2$, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have noticed correctly $f(x + nt) \ge f(x) - nt^2$ for each $n$. This was a key point.

Now, first try to see how to fit this to $x+y$ and do the bounding by $\epsilon$ later. Do not fix the $t$ beforehand. You can *define* it so that it fits nicely.
Just set $t_n= y/n$ for each $n$. Then $x+ y= x + nt_n$ for each $n$.

Then, apply this to bound $f(x+ y)$ from below, and finally  do an argument with $\epsilon$.